# Flutter app reciving json file from server

Tags: android, node.js, json, flutter

I want to send json data from my server ( just some basic node js server) to my application and i want to see in console that i recived this data and print it.

Json file (just for it, nothing particular)

```
[
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
    "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "qui est esse",
    "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 3,
    "title": "ea molestias quasi exercitationem repellat qui ipsa sit aut",
    "body": "et iusto sed quo iure\nvoluptatem occaecati omnis eligendi aut ad\nvoluptatem doloribus vel accusantium quis pariatur\nmolestiae porro eius odio et labore et velit aut"
  }

]
```

Server code

```
var http=require('http');
var fs=require('fs');
var file=fs.readFileSync('tmp.json','utf8'); //tmp is name of my json file
var server=http.createServer(function(req,res)
{
 res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}); 
 res.end(file);  
});
server.listen(3000,'127.0.0.1');
```

Code from Flutter Application, responsible for getting file and print it

```
class AwesomeButtonState extends State<AwesomeButton>
{
  Future<String>GetData() async
  {
    var responce=await http.get(
      Uri.encodeFull("127.0.0.1:3000"),
      headers: {
      "Accept": "text/json" 
      }
    );
    //print(responce.body);
    List data= json.decode(responce.body); //konwersja na liste
    print(data[1]["title"]); 
      }

  }
```

The error that i recive is:

```
ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Scheme not starting with alphabetic character (at character 1)
```

When i try to get data from other server e.x. http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts everything works fine, so i dont think that's something with app, but rather the server. I've already tried to change Content-Type in server but it didnt work.

Comment: Try changing headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      } i guess this is what causing the problem

Comment: It didnt work. Still same error

Comment: have you accessed it directly through something like postman to see if anything is wrong with the json?

Comment: I can access my localhost server and i can see entire json file printed, so i dont think thats json file problem

Comment: When u Print(data) ; what does it show

Comment: It shows nothing, only error message. I even tried to comment every single print

Comment: So, as nucleartux wrote as answer, adding http:// worked, but now i have diffrent error:
Unhandled Exception: SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111, address = 127.0.0.1, port = 33845

I dont know why it shows such a port

Comment: Change the IP address to 10.0.2.2 instead of 127.0.0.1, because you are running it on an emulator. 10.0.2.2 is the ip address for the computer hosting the emulator.

Answer (score 1):

"Scheme not starting with alphabetic character (at character 1)" Error says what you schema ( = url) is not correct.
Try call

```
http.get("http://127.0.0.1:3000"....
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it works i needed to change 2 thing

1. Add http:// before my localhost ip adress
2. Change my localhost ip adress in code to 10.0.2.2: [port] because android that's why

So final working code line looks like this [ in flutter app]

```
Uri.encodeFull("http://10.0.2.2:3000")
```